# How to schedule a task for every two hours in c# asp.net application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, parallel-processing, task

I have a scenario in which I have to sync my local database to my online database. I am doing that with Microsoft sync framework. Now I want to execute this function in my web c# application so that after every 2 hour this should executed(Without window scheduler). How I can do this? please give a code example as I am new in this area. 
I have used [this code](https://dhavalupadhyaya.wordpress.com/2008/08/30/how-to-create-scheduled-jobs-in-net-web-applications/) in my application suggested by Hari and it is running. First time the code is executed fine but when it reaches next time stamp the, a message displayed in output window "The thread 0x22d4 has exited with code 0 (0x0)." In no work is done, then again and again when the time comes it shows the same message and no work is done. I am new to threading so, I think I am missing some setting to allow this thread. please any one can help?

Comment: Have you considered using an online CRON job? Is that acceptable in your scenario?

Comment: You can use online service which will call your controller action after 2 hours and on action you can sync your databases.
I have used https://uptimerobot.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two approaches which you can take in such scenarios,

### **1. Dedicated Online CRON Job (Recommended):**

You can create a separate CRON Job this can be Azure Web job and schedule it accordingly. You can move your code to sync the DB into this CRON Job and forget about it, it will execute every 2 hours and do your sync.

### **2. Write a Scheduler Job in side ASP.NET Web Application:**

You can use .Net Framework to write a simple scheduler job and schedule it accordingly and register it using the Global.asax and let it run every 2 hours.

I found one link which demonstrates the second approach with a code sample: [Click here for tutorial](https://dhavalupadhyaya.wordpress.com/2008/08/30/how-to-create-scheduled-jobs-in-net-web-applications/)

**Regards,
Hari**

Comment: Thanks bro, this helped a lot and resolved my problem for which I was striving hard. I used 2nd option.

Comment: You are welcome @AsifAziz, but still you should consider upgrading to first suggestion. As it guarantee syncing of DB even if your web application is down.

Comment: Bro this was nice solution but it works fine first time when I run application but nest time a message come in output window "The thread 0x3b80 has exited with code 0 (0x0)". and no work is done. I think the thread is no allowed to execute.

Comment: Ya maybe because the resources are being released for the web application once it finish all the operations. To test this, start a method being executed from the web application and then check if the scheduler is getting triggered or not. In other words keep the application active and then the scheduler will work I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely, You need some sort of scheduling mechanism and an OS-level service to keep your scheduler engine alive. My recommendation is to create a [widows service](http://follow%20this%20https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/8a67c0/create-and-install-windows-service-step-by-step-in-C-Sharp/) and you may use [Quartz](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/) Scheduler engine to schedule your task.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a windows service and handle the scheduling yourself.

Another option is to use Hangfire (https://www.hangfire.io) to run repeat background tasks within your web application.

Answer (score -1):

I agree with @@Hari Govind. If it is possible to use Microsoft azure then create WebJob with some crown expression by which you will be able to run your task every two hours.

Comment: Please add this as comment, for my answer and not as an Answer to the question.